# Phone validation REGEX for Twilio

Tags: regex, twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to create a regular expression to force users to enter only phone numbers of the format accepted by Twilio API. With prefix of form +40 (eg.: +40123456789) not 0040 and without delimiters. Only the character + and numbers.

I came up with this so far `\+\d{10,}`.

Is this a good one? If not can you please improve on it?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

- the phone number should contain the prefix of the country and the phone number
- the prefix is not fixed to +40(Romanian prefix). That is just an example.
- the prefix should start with `+` not with `00`
- the number should not have delimiters

Good example: +40123456789
Bad example: (074) 352-7819

Comment: Could you please share exact requirements and supply good and bad examples? I see no leading spaces. Is `+` obligatory? Minimum 10 digits? If yes, you can use `(?<=\W|^)\+?[1-9][0-9]{9,}(?=\W|$)`. See https://regex101.com/r/rI6gB9/1.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the minimal Regex validation as it has been provided in their documentation:
`^\+[1-9]\d{1,14}$`

Cfr: https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164#regex-matching-for-e164

Answer (score 2):

The pattern provided will expect to match a plus sign followed by 10 digits. If you string starts with letters or white spaces or any other character, that regular expression will still succeed.

If you want the following:

1. Starts with `+40`
2. Contains a total of 10 digits and plus sign).
3. Nothing else from the above

The following should do the trick: `^\+40\d{8}$`. An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/hN6aW5/1).